# unable to map network drive using path and password

Tags: path, remote-desktop, network-drive

I am using rackspace as my cloud hosting and I just created a new server.  I'm attempting to access the remote C: drive from my local machine using the following path: \xx.xxx.xx.xxx\c$.  This works fine on my original server, but on the new one I'm not able to get it to work.  Is there some specific setting on the remove server to make it accessible that I'm forgetting to configure?

Thanks.

EDIT: I'm getting a diagnostic error saying the drive is online but is not responding to connection attempts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer to this.

In the windows firewall settings, the following rule must be enabled:

DFS Management (SMB-In) on Port 445